# Accessing BcdStore from Delphi

Tags: delphi, wmi, bcdstore

I'm trying to convert this code fragment into Delphi and I got stuck on the `for each objWBL in colObjects`.

```
if not objBcdStore.EnumerateObjects( &h10200003, colObjects ) then
    WScript.Echo "ERROR objBcdStore.EnumerateObjects( &h10200003 ) failed."
    WScript.Quit(1)
end if

for each objWBL in colObjects
    WScript.Echo ""
    WScript.Echo "Windows Boot Loader"
    WScript.Echo "-------------------"

    WScript.Echo "identifier              " & GetBcdId( objWBL.Id )

    If objWBL.Id = current then

      if not objWBL.GetElement(BcdOSLoaderInteger_NumberOfProcessors, objElement ) then
          WScript.Echo "ERROR WBL GetElement for " & Hex(BcdOSLoaderInteger_NumberOfProcessors) & " failed."
          WScript.Quit(1)
      end if
      WScript.Echo "numproc              " & objElement.Integer

      if not objWBL.GetElement(BcdOSLoaderBoolean_UseBootProcessorOnly, objElement ) then
          WScript.Echo "ERROR WBL GetElement for " & Hex(BcdOSLoaderBoolean_UseBootProcessorOnly) & " failed."
          WScript.Quit(1)
      end if
      WScript.Echo "onecpu              " & objElement.Boolean

    end if
next
```

My partial q&d translation (caution, must be Admin to run it):

```
uses
  OleAuto,
  ActiveX;

function GetObject(const objectName: String): IDispatch;
var
  bindCtx: IBindCtx;
  moniker: IMoniker;
  chEaten: Integer;
begin
  OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, bindCtx));
  OleCheck(MkParseDisplayName(bindCtx, StringToOleStr(objectName), chEaten, moniker));
  OleCheck(moniker.BindToObject(bindCtx, nil, IDispatch, Result));
end;

procedure TForm44.btnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  colObjects   : OleVariant;
  objBcdStore  : OleVariant;
  objWMIService: OleVariant;
begin
  objWMIService := GetObject('winmgmts:{impersonationlevel=Impersonate,(Backup,Restore)}!root/wmi:BcdStore');
  if not objWMIService.OpenStore('', objBcdStore) then
    Caption := 'error'
  else begin
    objBcdStore.EnumerateObjects($10200003, colObjects);
    //???
  end;
end;
```

[EnumerateObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362686%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is defined as

```
boolean EnumerateObjects(
  [in]   uint32 Type,
  [out]  BcdObject Objects[]
);
```

I have no idea how to walk over the BcdObject array in Delphi.

Comment: I take it you tried "for x in y do z()" syntax, and that didn't work?

Comment: Actually, I didn't. However, it doesn't work: "[DCC Error] Unit44.pas(55): E2430 for-in statement cannot operate on collection type 'OleVariant'"

Comment: I kind of thought OleVariant-variant-arrays and for-in wouldn't work, but I just wondered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you must use the [`VarArrayLowBound`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Variants.VarArrayLowBound) and [`VarArrayHighBound`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Variants.VarArrayHighBound) functions to get the bounds of the variant array returned by the `EnumerateObjects` function  and then you can use a `for` loop to iterate over the elements of the array.

check this sample

```
Uses
 ComObj,
 ActiveX;

function GetObject(const objectName: String): IDispatch;
var
  bindCtx: IBindCtx;
  moniker: IMoniker;
  chEaten: Integer;
begin
  OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, bindCtx));
  OleCheck(MkParseDisplayName(bindCtx, StringToOleStr(objectName), chEaten, moniker));
  OleCheck(moniker.BindToObject(bindCtx, nil, IDispatch, Result));
end;


procedure TForm44.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  colObjects   : OleVariant;
  objBcdStore  : OleVariant;
  objWMIService: OleVariant;

  i : Integer;
  objWBL : OleVariant;
begin
  objWMIService := GetObject('winmgmts:{impersonationlevel=Impersonate,(Backup,Restore)}!root/wmi:BcdStore');
  if not objWMIService.OpenStore('', objBcdStore) then
    Caption := 'error'
  else
  begin
    objBcdStore.EnumerateObjects($10200003, colObjects);
       if not VarIsNull(colObjects) and VarIsArray(colObjects) then
       for i := VarArrayLowBound(colObjects, 1) to VarArrayHighBound(colObjects, 1) do
       begin
          objWBL:=colObjects[i];
          //do your stuff here


       end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to RRUZ for answer - I learned something new - but sadly the correct answer was "Don't do that" (how typical!).

It turned out that by enumerating the `Windows Boot Loader` objects, one can't find out which of the objects is the "current" one. As I finally found out (thanks to the [Hey, Scripting Guy!](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.07.heyscriptingguy.aspx) article from the July 2008 issue of the TechNet Magazine), the correct way is to open the loader object directly by it's well-known ID. (Which is, again, well-hidden and not well-known. The only official documentation I managed to find on the well-known BCD GUIDs is [Boot Configuration Data in Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463059.aspx) document.)

The sample code below first opens BCD WMI object. Then it opens the default store and shows the information for the `{current}` boot entry object (accessed by the well-known ID).

Next it opens the `Windows Boot Manager` object (by using its well-known ID), reads its `DefaultObject` element to determine the GUID of the default boot entry, opens this object by its GUID and shows the information.

`ShowLoaderInfo` displays only `ID` (GUID), `Description` and `NumberOfProcessors` (which was an information I wanted to get from the BCD). A funny trick here is that the latter is of the `BcdIntegerElement` type, which returns its value through the Integer property, with a "feature" that the returned value is not an integer but a string. A note from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa362650%28v=VS.85%29) explains:

> The integer value of the element. The value is passed as a string
>   because Automation does not natively support 64-bit integers.

(Yeah, great! Why does it have to be 64-bit anyway? Are 2 billion processors not enough?)

For a full list of supported `Windows Boot Loader` elements see [BcdOSLoaderElementTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362670%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

```
program ShowBCDInfo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ComObj,
  ActiveX;

const
  Description                 = $12000004; //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa362652(v=VS.85)
  UseBootProcessorOnly        = $26000060; //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa362641(v=VS.85)
  NumberOfProcessors          = $25000061;
  ForceMaximumProcessors      = $26000062;
  ProcessorConfigurationFlags = $25000063;
  DefaultObject               = $23000003; //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa362641(v=VS.85)

  CurrentGUID = '{fa926493-6f1c-4193-a414-58f0b2456d1e}'; //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463059.aspx
  WBMGUID     = '{9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}';

function GetObject(const objectName: String): IDispatch;
var
  bindCtx: IBindCtx;
  moniker: IMoniker;
  chEaten: Integer;
begin
  OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, bindCtx));
  OleCheck(MkParseDisplayName(bindCtx, StringToOleStr(objectName), chEaten, moniker));
  OleCheck(moniker.BindToObject(bindCtx, nil, IDispatch, Result));
end;

procedure ShowLoaderInfo(const name: string; const obj: OleVariant);
var
  objElement: OleVariant;
begin
  Writeln(Format('%s ID: %s', [name, string(obj.id)]));
  if obj.GetElement(Description, objElement) then
    Writeln(Format('Description: %s', [objElement.String]));
  if obj.GetElement(NumberOfProcessors, objElement) then
    Writeln(Format('NumProc: %s', [objElement.Integer]));
end;

procedure ShowBcdInfo;
var
  objBcdStore  : OleVariant;
  objWBL       : OleVariant;
  objWBM       : OleVariant;
  objWMIService: OleVariant;
begin
  objWMIService := GetObject('winmgmts:{(Backup,Restore)}\\.\root\wmi:BcdStore');
  if not objWMIService.OpenStore('', objBcdStore) then
    Writeln('*** error opening store')
  else begin
    if objBcdStore.OpenObject(CurrentGUID, objWBL) then
      ShowLoaderInfo('{current}', objWBL);
    if objBcdStore.OpenObject(WBMGuid, objWBM) and
       objWBM.GetElement(DefaultObject, objWBL) and
       objBcdStore.OpenObject(string(objWBL.ID), objWBL)
    then
      ShowLoaderInfo('{default}', objWBL);
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    OleInitialize(nil);
    try
      ShowBCDInfo;
    finally OleUninitialize; end;
    Readln;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```